# External image vulnerabilities

Tags: php, image, security, xss, csrf

What security holes can appear on my site by including external images via `img` tag and how to avoid them?

I'm currently only checking the extension and `mime-type` of image on submission (that can be changed after `URL` is submitted) and `URL` is sanitized before putting it in `src` attribute.

Comment: Can i ask how you're checking the extension specifically, and when you say that things can be changed after the URL is submitted, do you mean by the user, or by you?

Comment: Surely by the user (owner of the server where the image is stored). It's not so hard to put an AddHandler into .htaccess and mark .jpeg as executable. All web-sniffers are made this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a differentiation to be made here between *who* is at risk.

If all you're doing is storing URLs, and not uploading images to your server, then your site is *probably* safe, and any potential risk is to your users who view your site.

In essence, you're putting your trust in the reliability of the browser manufacturers. Things *might* be fine, but if a security hole in some browser one of your users uses were to arise that involved incorrectly parsing images that contain malicious code, then it's your users who will end up paying for it (you might find [GIFAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifar) interesting).

It comes down to whether you trust the browser manufacturers to make secure software, and whether you trust your users to not upload URLs to images that might contain exploits for certain browsers. What might be secure now might not be secure come the next release.

Comment: Thank you! For the nice answer and for sharing information about GIFAR

Answer (score 3):

The primary holes that can be exposed are those where corrupted images cause buffer overflows within the browser, allowing arbitrary code execution.

If you're only putting the images into an `<img>` tag there *shoudln't* be any vulnerabilities relating to sending alternative MIME types, but never underestimate the stupidity of some web browser developers...

Comment: So the main problem are browsers ? Are there some ways to secure these external images or something ?

Comment: Download them, scan them for known vulnerabilities. But I fear nobody does, that's normally why it's so important to actually use safe browsers. I wish there would be some reports/projects finding out how safe at all web-browsers are today. When I see how often my operating system updates, the browser should update every two days as well I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

Well, obviously, you're not doing any checks on the data, so the data can be anything (the mime-type reported by the remote server doesn't necessarily tell the truth). Plus, as you said, the data on the remote server can be changed since you're never looking at it after submission.

As such, if the link is put into lets say an <img src="..."/>, then any vulnerability that a browser might have in the image handling can be exploited.

"Sanitizing" the URL doesn't help with anything: somebody submitting a link that points to a 'bad' image isn't going to attack his own server.

Comment: And what kind of checks should I make on the data ?